# How to merge two different sized lists into one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
List1=[['Širvintos', 'Alauša ', 'Musninkų g. 4 Širvintos', '2022-04-09'], 
['Vilnius', 'Alauša ', 'Kalvarijų g. 204G Vilnius', '2022-04-09'], 
['Vilnius', 'Alauša ', 'Šiaurės g. 39 Vilnius', '2022-04-09']]
```

and

```
List2=[['1.699 ', '1.799 ', '0.00'], 
['1.689 ', '1.789 ', '0.699 '], 
['1.749 ', '1.809 ', '0.679 ']]
```

I used `zip()` function and got the outcome:

```
[[['Širvintos', 'Alauša ', 'Musninkų g. 4 Širvintos', '2022-04-09'], ['1.699 ', '1.799 ', '0.00']], 
[['Vilnius', 'Alauša ', 'Kalvarijų g. 204G Vilnius', '2022-04-09'], ['1.689 ', '1.789 ', '0.699 ']], 
[['Vilnius', 'Alauša ', 'Šiaurės g. 39 Vilnius', '2022-04-09'], ['1.749 ', '1.809 ', '0.679 ']]]
```

Although two lists were zipped, it is not my desirable outcome. I would like to get something like this:

```
[['Širvintos', 'Alauša ', 'Musninkų g. 4 Širvintos', '2022-04-09','1.699 ', '1.799 ', '0.00'], 
['Vilnius', 'Alauša ', 'Kalvarijų g. 204G Vilnius', '2022-04-09','1.689 ', '1.789 ', '0.699 '], 
['Vilnius', 'Alauša ', 'Šiaurės g. 39 Vilnius', '2022-04-09','1.749 ', '1.809 ', '0.679 ']]
```

I want to remove inner square brackets, but I can't find a way to do it. How should I approach this?

Comment: Well, each list in your result contains two lists, that you want to concatenate together. Do you know how to repeat a process with each element of a list? Do you know how to get the two lists from one of your result lists, and put them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[a+b for a,b in zip(List1,List2)]
```